# How to make a background of a button transparent with visible border in Android?

Tags: android, android-view

This is the coding of the button. I want to make only borders visible and background of the button should be invisible.But with this code everything is becoming invisible.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

[image]

I want my button to look like this.

Comment: create rectangle drawable

Comment: You can create background drawables for this and use it as background of button.

Comment: @Abhishek Have you implemented ?

Comment: @ Mohammad Arman Yeah Implemented. thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/button_bg"/>
```

button_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
      android:radius="2dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="2px"
      android:color="@color/your_border_color" />
</shape>
```

Comment: 2px should be changed to 2dp

Answer (score 1):

use drawable, create shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp" /> //your radius
    <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#FFF" /> //your stroke size
</shape>
```

Then implement it in xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:background="@drawable/shape" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your button inside a rectangle shape like this :

create butoon_backgound.xml in the drawable directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#00FF00"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/butoon_backgound"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"

</RelativeLayout>
```

stroke attribute is the sroke of your border

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Create One button_border.xml file in your drawable folder and paste this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
```

add button to your xml layout and set background as

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"/>
```